# Improving performance of inserting into Mongo from ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mqtt, activemq-artemis

The basic idea of the following code is I read messages off an ActiveMQ Artemis installation and insert them into a MongoDB instance.

It works well for up to a hundred or so messages per second but crashes if I throw a few thousand at it. My first guess would be the constant opening and closing of database connections. Should I also think about using an in-memory store and doing bulk database inserts?

The code is all running in node using the mqtt and mongodb npm packages. The code below, the database and the queue are all running in docker containers if it makes any difference.

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt'),
client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://mq:1883', {
    username: "*************",
    password: "*************"
}),
MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID,
assert = require('assert'),
url = 'mongodb://db:27017/uo-readings';

client.on('connect', function () {
    client.subscribe('readings');
});

client.on('error', function(error){
    console.log(error)
});

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {

    console.log(message.toString());

    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);

        console.log("Connected correctly to server.");

        db.collection('readings').insertOne(JSON.parse(message.toString()), function(err, result) {
            assert.equal(err, null);
            console.log("Inserted a document into the readings collection.");
        });

        client.end(function(){
            console.log("Closing Connection.");
            db.close();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You guessed right! You are opening a connexion at each request and it is VERY bad thing. Just connect outside of the client.on and you are good to go. Bulking is a good idea too, but your issue is definitively the connection

Comment: Thanks Jonathan - moving the client.on('message') function inside my DB connection did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See @Jonathan Muller's comment above